# Docker container startup hangs while trying to run voting app

Tags: linux, docker, docker-compose

I did the following:

```
https://github.com/dockersamples/example-voting-app

cd example-voting-app
```

Inside that there are number of files/folders

```
MAINTAINERS
LICENSE
Jenkinsfile
ExampleVotingApp.sln
README.md
docker-stack-windows-1809.yml
docker-stack-simple.yml
docker-compose.yml
docker-compose-windows.yml
docker-compose-windows-1809.yml
docker-compose-simple.yml
docker-compose-k8s.yml
docker-compose-javaworker.yml
architecture.png
kube-deployment.yml
k8s-specifications
docker-stack.yml
docker-stack-windows.yml
result
vote
worker
```

I did `cd vote` and executed following commands

```
docker build . -t voting-app
docker run -p 5000:80 voting-app
```

After I run `docker run` command, I see the following output, and nothing is happening . I am clueless, as there is no error messages etc.

```
[root@osboxes vote]# docker run -p 5000:80 voting-app
[2020-06-16 17:59:27 +0000] [1] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 19.10.0
[2020-06-16 17:59:27 +0000] [1] [INFO] Listening at: http://0.0.0.0:80 (1)
[2020-06-16 17:59:27 +0000] [1] [INFO] Using worker: sync
[2020-06-16 17:59:27 +0000] [9] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 9
[2020-06-16 17:59:27 +0000] [10] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 10
[2020-06-16 17:59:27 +0000] [11] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 11
[2020-06-16 17:59:27 +0000] [12] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 12
```

Please guide how to fix this issue, and how to get the vote app running on container.

My OS details are as follows:

```
NAME="CentOS Linux"
VERSION="7 (Core)"
```

Thanks

Comment: Many people are strugging with this I think its no longer working. Hopefully we could find a solution here :)

Comment: This is distributed app with different containers that you need to have running. Did you start this using docker-compose?

Comment: Have you visited `localhost:5000`? If it's running with no errors, that could well mean it's simply running as it should be.

Comment: I just started the voting app. That is where i am facing problem. I have not started other apps. 

my application is failing to start. So no point in vising the URL (I visited http://192.168.56.101:5000 but page is not loading. 192.168.56.101 is the IP of my VM)

Comment: @SiHa I guess you are right. I tried to visit 192.168.56.101:5000 after 15 mins and I am able to access the page now. Strangely it was not working earlier. Now if i terminate the process using Ctrl + C, and re-run it again, i am able to access the url 192.168.56.101:5000 immediately. Earlier i was not able to.

Answer (score 1):

In my earlier answer, i got the app working, by building and running each image individually.

Finally, after spending few hours, I am finally able to create `docker-compose.yml` file and able to run the entire application using the following command:

`docker-compose up`

Hope it helps other who are struggling to make this application work.

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: "3"

services:
 redis:
  image: redis

 db:
  image: postgres:9.4
  environment:
    - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres
    - POSTGRES_HOST_AUTH_METHOD=trust

 vote:
  image: voting-app
  ports:
   - 5000:80
  links:
   - redis

 worker:
  image: worker-app
  links:
    - db
    - redis

 result:
  image: result-app
  ports:
    - 5001:80
  links:
    - db
```

Comment: Chaurasta thank you so much , i spent hours tryingto run the app manually without using docker compose. but using docker compose was very quickly

Answer (score 0):

After code checkout, I followed the following steps, and got the voting application to run.

**change to vote directory**

```
docker run -d --name=redis redis

docker build . -t voting-app

docker run -p 5000:80 --link redis:redis voting-app

docker run -d --name=db -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres postgres:9.4
```

**change to worker directory**

```
docker build . -t worker-app

docker run --link redis:redis --link db:db worker-app
```

**change to result directory**

```
docker build . -t result-app

docker run -p 5001:80 --link db:db result-app
```

**Access the URLs**

```
http://<IP>:5000/

http://<IP>:5001/
```

Replace the IP with IP of your machine. Now I can access both the URLs.